# Как скрыть от индексации припаркованный домен?

Tags: seo

Есть 1 основной сайт и к нему ещё припаркован домен. Каким образом можно скрыть припаркованный домен от индексации гуглом?

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову - менять robots.txt в зависимости от домена, в .htaccess. При запросе домена, который нужно скрыть, отдавать robots.txt с содержимым

User-agent: *
Disallow: /

Comment: Что вы понимаете под словом "припаркован"?

Answer (score 2):

Если он должен стать зеркалом, то нужно делать:

- 301 редирект с одного домена на другой
- В robots.txt указать основной домен
- В настройках гугла указать его как домен

Если Нужно вообще запретить индексацию, то нужно:

- Ботам гугла возвращался статус например 404 для этого можно сделать настройка на сервере
- В robots.txt по домену должна быть запрещена индексация `User-agent: * Disallow: /`